# Override onAuthenticationSuccess in symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I am trying to upgrade my Symfony app to 5.4.  It seems that the security system has had a lot of work done which makes things simpler.  I have my app authenticating the user using the form_login system which now requires no code due to the new `enable_authenticator_manager`: true option in `security.yaml`.  All good.  I would like to override the behaviour of just the `onAuthenticationSuccess()` method so that I can do some gathering of tokens from external sites as the user is logged in.  So my question is:

Can I JUST override the onAuthenticationSuccess method without having to write a complete custom authentication handler?

What I have tried so far (just trying to override the method - my logic will come later):

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UserNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\RememberMeBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\CustomCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($target = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($target);
        }
        return new RedirectResponse(
            $this->router->generate('app_homepage')
        );
    }
}
```

but this gives me errors

```
Error: Class App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator::getLoginUrl, Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AuthenticatorInterface::authenticate)
```

Comment: You could use the security event system. Or decorate the `security.authenticator.form_login` service.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#security-events

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.  Would you be able to provide an example as to how I could achieve this please?  The documentation that you link to is not very detailed as to how to do this.  Thank you.